# enabling check box to deactivate sound in android

Tags: android, checkbox, soundpool, android-sharedpreferences

Iam creating a simple game in android,when l opn app and the sound is starting   ,l am want to deactivate the sound with check box, it can deactivate and it shows that music deactivated but the music still on, any help is appreciated.

```
public class Setting extends Activity {
 public static MediaPlayer Sounds;
private CheckBox sound;
private Boolean isChecked = false;
public void Is_checked() {
 if (isChecked) {

    Sounds.start();

    Toast.makeText(Setting.this, "Sound is activated ",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

   else {
    Sounds.stop();
    Toast.makeText(Setting.this, "Sound is deactivated ",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 }

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.setting);
Sounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backmusic);
isChecked = false;
addListenerOnsound();

 }

protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
isChecked = false;
addListenerOnsound();
   }

    private void save(final boolean isChecked) {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("check", isChecked);
editor.commit();
}

     private boolean load() {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check", false);
  }

   protected void onReStart() {
    super.onRestart();
    sound.setChecked(load());
 }

     @Override
       void onPause() {
             super.onPause();
       save(sound.isChecked());
        }

          @Override
        public void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
              sound.setChecked(load());
           }

         public void addListenerOnsound() {

     sound = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sound);

   sound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

          if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            isChecked = true;
            Is_checked();

           }

          if (!((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            isChecked = false;
            Is_checked();

        }}  });}}
```

Comment: Do you want to permanently stop the sound once checkbox is clicked or should it resume from the position when it was paused ?

Comment: @varunkr l want to resume from the position that paused,thank you.

Comment: Then just use Sounds.pause() instead of Sounds.stop() as mentioned in the answer !!

Comment: dear @varunkr this is my assignment it is important to use sharedpreference .

Comment: Why? There is no need of SharedPreference here ? Should the sound resume even when app is restarted? Is that what the real problem is ? Coz I  don't see any use of SharedPreference in the existing question!!

Comment: @varunkr you are right, but when l tried to start from beginning then l wrote your code and l clicked the setting ,the emulator screen was black instead of showing check box. Iam trying to fix it.

Comment: @varunkr  if you have time please, l really need your help.for saving key data.

Comment: @varunkr Iam appreciate you help dear varunkr,but my work is too much, it is not easy to post all of it .if you want l can send it by email.and now l have another problem saving data in android, it seems you have a good background in android

Comment: @varunkr  
l try to make a game for my assignment, l just want to save players name but really l donot have any idea how to do it, if you have time please could you help me?

Comment: @varunkr thank you so much l appreciate your concern , actually l know  that by using shared preference, l have a poor background  on android ,l donot have any idea how to do it, please if you have time please can you help me just for saving players name, that is save me, l can sent my assignment by email.

Comment: @varunkr many thanks, you save me.(r.Sedeeq4872@student.leedsbeckett.ac.uk) that is my email if l just know you email in order to send you the assignment.

Comment: Dear @varunkr l have sent my assignment, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to resume the audio you should simply use

```
Sounds.pause();
```

instead of

```
Sounds.stop()
```

But if you want it to start from the beginning, do this.

```
public void Is_checked() {
        if (isChecked) {

            Sounds.start();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Sound is activated ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else {
            Sounds.stop();
            Sounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backmusic);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Sound is deactivated ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Rezan What is the original problem then? Because I don't see any need of SharedPreference here !!

Comment: you are right, but when l tried to start from beginning then l wrote your code and l clicked the setting ,the emulator screen was black instead of showing check box

Comment: @Rezan Oh, I tried this code on my own device and it worked fine, you should try it on a real device. Emulator is not very reliable. It is slow too !!

Comment: public class Setting extends Activity {

 public static MediaPlayer Sounds;

 private CheckBox sound;
 private Boolean isChecked = true;

 public void Is_checked() {
        if (isChecked) {

            Sounds.start();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Sound is activated ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else {
            Sounds.stop();
            Sounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backmusic);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Sound is deactivated ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Comment: @Rezan This looks fine, do u get any error or just the black screen. I tried it on my Nexus5 and works perfectly.

Comment: @Rezan I suggest you try it on an actual device once, just re-initializing the mediaplayer shouldn't cause a black screen.  Please try it on an actual device.

Comment: l have tried on my phone it is the same result, thank you.

Comment: @Rezan Thnx for accepting the answer btw. Can you post your full activity code after the changes, I will try it on my device, coz works for me, may be you made a mistake somewhere !!

Comment: Iam appreciate you help dear varunkr,but my work is too much, it is not easy to post all of it .if you want l can send it by email.and now l have another problem saving data in android, it seems you have a good background in android.

Comment: dear varunkr if you have time please, l really need your help.for saving key data

Comment: @Rezan what is the problem ?

Comment: l try to make a game for my assignment, l just want to save players name but really l donot have any idea how to do it, if you have time please could you help me?

Comment: @Rezan You can do this using SharedPreferences !!

Comment: @Rezan If you face any doubts or problem feel free to ask !!